# Cannot type in emulator search bar

Tags: ios, emulation

When I use an iOS device for debugging, I can type and retype into the search bar at the top (I am running a webkit browser inside my app). If I do this in the emulator I can type in it when the search bar is empty but after I have search for something and it is filled with a URL, I cannot retype into it as the search bar moves back and forth when I try to select it.

It works perfectly fine on an actual iOS device but on the emulator it will toggle.

It uses the basic webkit library: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

I expect it to work like on the iOS device and it does if I toggle the software keyboard but without it, it doesn't.

[image: Search bar is inaccessible here]

Answer (score 0):

From the engineer who fixed it:

It's actually strange. I'm not sure if this PR is relying on an undocumented behaviour, but it should be safe even if that changes. Here's what's happening.

iOS should fire UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification when the keyboard is going to be displayed, and UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification when the keyboard is going to be hidden. For both notifications, this code retrieves the frame of the keyboard:

let beginRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
let endRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
What's strange is that in the iOS simulator, if the software keyboard is toggled off (so simulating an external keyboard), UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification is never fired (which is understandable) and UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification is fired both when a text box becomes first responder (i.e. gains focus) and when the textbox resigns first responder (i.e. loses focus). I guess the rationale is that these notifications are fired for the software keyboard and in both cases the keyboard is hidden. Empirically, in iOS 12 (and iPhone X):

A. When a text box becomes first responder, beginRect.size.height=0 and endRect.size.height ~54. Both origin.y remains at ~812 (out of the screen).
B. When a text box resigns first responder, beginRect.size.height ~54 and endRect.size.height=0. Both origin.y remains at ~812 (out of the screen).

The fix is to test for A and ignore it when handling UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification